# Files not appearing when directory is being read

Tags: android, kotlin

I have two mp3 files in a directory that is being read but only the '.thumbnails' folder is being logged.

This is what gets logged

D/Files: Path: /storage/emulated/0/Music

D/Files: Size: 1

D/Files: FileName:.thumbnails

```
  fun readFiles(){
        val path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path + "/Music"
        Log.d("Files", "Path: $path")
        val directory = File(path)
        val files = directory.listFiles()
        Log.d("Files", "Size: " + files.size)
        for (i in files.indices) {
            Log.d("Files", "FileName:" + files[i].name)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you add the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` to your manifest file ?

Comment: Yes, Is it expected to post the manifest file along with the code. I wasn't sure.

Comment: What's the correct path of your mp3 files (using File explorer)?

Comment: You mean the Device file explorer right? /storage/emulated/0/Music/10 Somebody Told Me.mp3

Comment: ,See my answer, I've tested it on my phone and it's worked

Answer (score 0):

1 - Make sure the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission is granted

```
fun readFiles() {
        val path = getAbsolutePath(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC));
        Log.d("Files", "Path: $path")
        val directory = File(path)
        val files = directory.listFiles()
        Log.d("Files", "Size: " + files.size)
        for (i in files.indices) {
            Log.d("Files", "FileName:" + files[i].name)
        }
    }

private fun getAbsolutePath(file: File?): String? {
    return if (file == null) "" else file.absolutePath
}
```

Logcat  :

```
2020-08-11 14:40:33.862 16137-16137/maa.app D/Files: Path: /storage/emulated/0/Music
2020-08-11 14:40:33.863 16137-16137/maa.app D/Files: Size: 2
2020-08-11 14:40:33.863 16137-16137/maa.app D/Files: FileName:10 Somebody Told Me.mp3
2020-08-11 14:40:33.863 16137-16137/maa.app D/Files: FileName:Musiclrc
```